# Detect alarm "Dismiss" event in running application?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone

I've built an application with a toggle switch that indicates to the user that an alarm is scheduled.

If my application is closed when the alarm fires, and the user clicks 'Dismiss' then launches my app, I can detect that the alarm has expired via ScheduledActionService.Find and set the toggle to the off position.

The problem I'm having is when my application is open and the alarm fires. In that case, when the user clicks dismiss and is returned to my application which was in the background, how do I detect the change in the alarm state?

Is there an event that I can listen for when an alarm is dismissed? 
If not, is there a way to detect when my app loses/gains focus due to an alarm dialog?

Thanks

Comment: I spent some time exploring _Application_Activated_ in App.xaml.cs but that only seems to fire during task switching, it's not firing after dismissing an alarm.  

I check the behavior of the the default alarm application on the phone and those toggle switches shut off after dismissing an alarm.

Comment: Hi, I just wonder how you can detect if the user has clicked the 'dismiss' button? I assume you just set the `ExpirationTime` to be the same as the `BeginTime`? But what if the user clicked `snooze` button instead? Then you probably shouldn't turn off the toggle? I am asking this because I am facing a problem that I dunno how to detect which button is clicked. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your `App.Xaml.cs`, you can subscribe to the `Obscured` and `Unobscured` events of your `RootFrame`.

```
    RootFrame.Obscured += new EventHandler<ObscuredEventArgs>(RootFrame_Obscured);
    RootFrame.Unobscured += new EventHandler(RootFrame_Unobscured);
```

When the alarm pops up, `RootFrame_Unobscured` will be fired; after you dismiss it, `RootFrame_Obscured` will be fired.

Comment: One thing to note for anyone planning to use this method... Don't solely rely on `RootFrame.Unobscured`. It could have been triggered by a notification from another application. When the event fires be sure to check if your alarm is still running.

Comment: Did you see my comment under your question? :)

Comment: I did. I thought that was specific to the snooze action. :) ..have you worked out how to detect a snoozed alarm? I haven't looked into it too much yet but I see that `ScheduledActionService.Find("ALARM_NAME").BeginTime;` still shows the original start time.

Comment: Another thing to add here. I was going crazy out trying to execute a method in `MainPage.xaml.cs` from `App.Xaml.cs`which I found is not recommended. 

As it turns out you can add an event handler for `Unobscured` to your main page using `(Application.Current as App).RootFrame.Obscured += new EventHandler<ObscuredEventArgs>(RootFrame_Obscured);`

Maybe this is obvious to some, but it took me a while to figure out.

Comment: hi may I know how you started your app when the alarm fires.